# Change fielderror style for a specific form only

Tags: css, forms, struts2

I have an `<s:form>` with id `searchbox`.

```
<s:form action="search" id="searchbox" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="query" placeholder="Enter movie title..." cssClass="searchfield" />
    <s:submit type="image" src="images/btn_search.gif" />
</s:form>
```

While I've seen answers to change the fielderror style globally using `.errorMessage`, I would like to change it *only* for the `searchbox` form and keep the `<s:head />` style for the rest.

Here is my CSS so far:

```
#searchbox {
    color: #2e0854;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.searchfield {
    width: 161px;
}
```

Unfortunately, the fielderror changes are not taking effect (the `searchfield` is okay).

Comment: What exactly do you want ti change?

Comment: Hi, the `fielderror` that appears on top of the `<s:textfield>` on invalid input (but only for the `searchbox` form).

Comment: `#searchbox .searchfield {}`?

Comment: @Morpheus I tried `#searchbox .errorMessage` since it was the `fielderror` that I wanted to change and it worked. But it was your comment that was the clue. If you can put that as an answer, I don't mind giving you some easy +reps. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ohtph added as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target in the following way:

```
#searchbox .searchfield {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Only the `.searchfield` which is under the `#searchbox` will be styled in the above example.